# Bowling balls colliding in space.

Tags: calculus

The physics problem is: if two bowling balls, each weighing 10 kg., are one meter apart in space, how long does it take for the two balls to collide. I'm an AP Physics and AP Calculus (BC) student in high school now. I assume this problem will involve an integral of some kind. All help is appreciated!

Comment: I assume you mean that they are only moving due to their mutual gravitational attraction, and there are no other forces involved? You also need to specify the size of the balls, since the answer would be rather trivial if they were 1 metre in diameter ...

Comment: Are they point bowling balls?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I forgot to mention there is no other gravitational pull on the bowling balls. The radius is 10 cm.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write the gravitational acceleration of each ball:  $a=-\frac {Gm}{r^2}$, where $r$ is the distance between the centers.  You want to find the time for it to move $\frac 12$ meter less the radius of a ball.  So $$a=\frac {d^2r}{dt^2}=\frac {dv}{dt}=-\frac {Gm}{r^2}$$  Now use the conservation of energy to express $v$ as a function of $r$-the loss of potential energy must be made up by kinetic energy.  Invert that and plug in for $r$ and you can integrate to get $v(t)$.  One more integral and you have $r(t)$.  Solve for the correct $r$ and you are there.

Comment: Is the potential energy the gravitational potential energy between the two balls? And if so, how would I find that?

Comment: That is correct.  It is just $-\frac {Gm^2}r+K$, where you choose $K$ for convenience.  Note I had dropped some squares in the original, now fixed.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a little confused. If I add the KE and GPE together, they equal what? I am trying to solve for r.

Comment: They equal whatever you start with.  You can choose $K$ so total energy is zero at the start.  It stays zero, so the GPE becomes negative and the KE becomes positive by the same amount.

Comment: When you first integrate, do you integrate with respect to t?

Comment: You will move the expression for $r^2$ in terms of $v$ to the left, the $dt$ to the right and integrate each side.  The equation is seperable.